# filter by parent field in django queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-urls

Hi i want to get all the items of a coffee shop by its slug . as it is clear it saves the pk not the slug in the model. Is there any way to get this instead of finding cafe pk and etc.
i am searching for some thing like just one query for it.
here is what i coded :

**url**

```
path(
     "<str:cafe_slug>/",
     ProfileList.as_view(),
     name="get_item_menu",
     ),
```

**in view**

```
 def get(self, request,cafe_slug):
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(cafe__slug=cafe_slug)
```

**model**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True,)
    cafe = models.ForeignKey(CoffeeShop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CoffeeShop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow from `coffeeshop` to related items via its related name. You haven't specified a `related_name` on Item, so the Django default is `item_set`. So, I think you want

```
coffee_shop = CoffeeShop.get( slug=whatever)
all_items = coffee_shop.item_set.all()
for item in all_items:
     # do stuff
```

`item_set` accepts all the methods that a queryset on `Item` accepts.

Personally I don't like default related_name and would always explicitly code `related_name="..."` on `Item.cafe`

If you just want the items, don't want the coffee_shop instance, but do know the slug which identifies the coffee_shop, then the query in your view is correct.

It's possible to use `prefetch_related` to get all the items related to the coffee_shop instance, but if you look at the SQL it is still two queries at that level

```
coffee_shop = CoffeeShop.prefetch_related('item_set').get( slug=whatever)
for item in coffee_shop.item_set.all():
     # won't hit the DB again provided you don't filter it further.
```